# ROS for x86 Galileo board using Yocto

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,

I'd like to create a Linux for my brand new x86 Intel Galileo board. The installed Linux is based on a Yocto-build, which is source-code available.

Has anyone got experience on how to package ROS with Yocto? I found only a year old thread on this topic, where it has been discussed for ARM devices. State back then was more or less, no further info available (yet)...

Best regards
Christoph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99466/ros-for-x86-galileo-board-using-yocto/) by [Christoph](https://answers.ros.org/users/6836/christoph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since beginning of this year there is a project that provides a build-layer for Yocto:

http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/OpenEmbedded

Stumbled over it by pure luck, but initial installation worked ok, so I can recommend it as a good starting Point :-)

Best regards
Christoph

---

Meanwhile I switched to Intel Edison (as Galileo turned out to be quite on the lowest possible edge of what is still doable for ROS). I have good experiences with meta-ros.

Good luck everyone! :-)

---

Originally posted by [Christoph](https://answers.ros.org/users/6836/christoph/) with karma: 96 on 2013-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-01-04**:
http://wiki.ros.org/IntelGalileo Also has some directions.